# gparted not detecting USB drive partitions in Fedora 27 only

Tags: fedora, gparted, partition-table

I've a 16 GB USB Flash drive with `GPT` partition table having 6 partition. `fdisk` and `gdisk` correctly detecting the partitions. Fedora 27, with mate desktop installed, can correctly mount all partitions but `gparted` showing only one partition with `iso9660` partition table. Further that `iso9660` partition is not deletable from `gparted`.

Surprisingly, `gparted` installed in `lUbuntu` in the same computer is detecting all 6 partitions and working fine with the same USB Drive.

If the drive is filled with `0` as follows it's becoming blank and `gparted` in Fedora 27 can modify it afterwards.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=2048
```

Or, If I format it with `block-size` 2048 it's working again with `gparted` on Fedora 27.

But if again I restore the backup with `dd` it's creating the same problem again. [I kept a backup of the disk using `dd` before formatting or filling with `0`]

So, I'm guessing some issue with block size, but what's the exact issue? And how `gparted` on `lUbuntu` is overcoming the issue? And is there any solution?

I've tried compiling `gparted` on Fedora 27 also with no fate.

Output of `gdisk -l /dev/sdb`

```
Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdb: 31277232 sectors, 14.9 GiB
Model: Extreme         
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 493A4183-68C3-4027-81AB-C48B76EDA317
Partition table holds up to 176 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 45
First usable sector is 46, last usable sector is 31277186
Partitions will be aligned on 4-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2129 sectors (1.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              64             219   78.0 KiB    0700  Gap0
   2             220            5979   2.8 MiB     EF00  EFI boot partition
   3            5980           30787   12.1 MiB    0700  Gap1
   4           32768         9345023   4.4 GiB     0700  
   5         9345024        27109375   8.5 GiB     0700  
   6        27109376        31277055   2.0 GiB     8300
```

What `gparted` detecting is

[image: gdisk showing wrong partition of USB drive in Fedora 27]

Any help is highly appreciated.

**NOTE:** I went through https://askubuntu.com/questions/675649/unable-to-delete-usb-drive-partitions-block-size-error also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have ISO signature remnants left on the drive.  Perhaps you copied a .iso file directory to the drive at some point?

To remove the ISO signatures see [GPT disk full of partitions looks like iso9660 with no partitions](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789898)

```
To resolve this run the following:
    sudo wipefs -o 0x8001 /dev/sdb
(It will surgically write zeros over 5 bytes of the ISO signature
without touching the GPT).
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I copied `supergrubdisk` using `dd` to make a bootable rescue drive.  I've removed the iso signature as the link saying and the problem is solved now.

Comment: But the USB drive is no more bootale..!! Is there a solution to keep the drive bootable and let `gparted` detect the partitions, as it's doing in `lUbuntu`?

Comment: If the USB flash drive was booting due to the ISO copied to it then you have a choice.  Either overwrite the USB flash drive with the ISO, so it will boot.  Or investigate using a distro on the USB flash drive and write the boot code for that distro to the USB flash drive.