# Cannot create partitions in gparted after imaging iso

Tags: partition, kali-linux, live-usb, iso, gparted

I have Kali Linux ISO image on a 64GB USB as explained in [official documentation](https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install).

I have also created persistence partition with **parted** in accordance with [official docs](https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence).

But now **gparted** shows the whole drive with no partitions:
[image]

Why does it not show all of the partitions? Is it an expected behaviour? Is there any way to make it understand and show all the partitions?

Here is the **lsblk** output:
[image: lsblk output]

I want to use all remaining space as a normal ExFAT storage.
What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [gparted not detecting USB drive partitions in Fedora 27 only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408921/gparted-not-detecting-usb-drive-partitions-in-fedora-27-only) for explanation from `gparted` developer. I had similar issue and asked that.

Latter I found newer versions of the software have this issue. So you may uninstall the current version `gparted` installed. Download source code of `gparted 25` compile and use that. I'm using `gparted 25` and it's working fine with the situation you're mentioned.

**NOTE** You may need to run `gparted 25` as root from **Terminal only**. If you want to launch it from GUI edit menu button corresponding to the software, pick run in terminal option and append `sudo` before starting command.

Comment: You are treating the symptoms, not the cause. Downgrading to an older version seems to make the error messages go away, but does not fix what's wrong with the disk. The message you linked to leads you to the real fix.

Comment: I know. But if I wipe the `iso` signature from the usb drive using `wipefs` (as mentioned in the link given in that answer), the usb drive loosing the bootable property. I'm really not an expert in this. May you please explain me how you've fixed it with newer version of `gparted`? It'll help me. Thanks.

Comment: I know the real fix would be using `wipefs -o 0x8001 /dev/sdX`. But I have marked this because this answer lead me to the correct answer... Ideally @Abhik Bose would post the correct workflow of the solution here...

Comment: The only problem seems to be the explanation: `wipefs` does not remove **iso** partition table, but does the opposite - removes any partition tables (**gpt** and **dos** in my case lol) before the **iso** partition table..

Comment: @Drew You can instruct `wipefs` to remove the `iso9660` signature selectively. First list all file system and partition table using `wipefs /dev/sdX` then from the output you can selectively remove `iso9660` like `sudo wipefs -o 0x8001 /dev/sdX` if 0x8001 is `iso9660` offsel. This will keep `gpt` intact. But after doing do the usb drive concerned loosing it's bootable property.

Answer (score 5):

Posting this here just to clarify @Abhik Bose's answer.

After imaging iso using `dd` the USB drive has multiple partition tables at the beginning of the disk.

gparted versions below v0.28  have ISO Partition Map Bugs and the bug fix resulted in another issue stated above.

So using old versions of gparted (before v0.28), for example v0.25, will fix this problem.
But there is a better way to do it.

Attach USB to another Linux machine (Like another Kali or Ubuntu VM)
Check it's name with `lsblk`

Then see all partition tables with `wipefs /dev/sdb`

[image]

As we can see there are two other partition table signatures in the beginning of the drive: 
gpt and dos (I guess it is the same as mbr)

Do:

```
wipefs -o 0x8001 /dev/sdX  # X - letter of the drive
```

This will surgically write zeros over 5 bytes of the ISO signature without touching the GPT (Or at least that is what [this post](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789898) says...)

Now run `gparted /dev/sdb` and see the result as expected:

[image]

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the persistence partition with gparted from the command line but not change it with

```
gparted /dev/sdb3
```

Otherwise you can change the filesystem from the command line the same way you created it with

```
mkfs.exfat -L myPartitionName /dev/sdb3
```

Best to do this from whichever distro you used to create the live usb from and not from within the live boot of Kali since the persistence partition contains any updates or packages you may have installed.

**Edit**

**The obvious bit**

Since the `dd'`copies the iso image to the usb it also copies the signature that your system needs to identify this as an iso image and boot appropriately. Without this information it won't boot, as you have found.

**The interesting bit**

Although you modified the partition table when you created `/dev/sdb3` and you can detect and mount the persistence FS you created `gparted` sees this as a single iso volume for the reasons given [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789898).

*The behaviour to report whole disk file systems before partition
  tables was changed in GParted 0.28.0 as part of bug 771244.  This was
  so that kernel reported partitions embedded within ISO images on whole
  disks aren't displayed so the user doesn't try to manipulate those
  ISO embedded partitions, which is impossible.*

Answer (score 0):

This is just an addition to @Abhik Bose and @Drew's answers.

After using wipefs for deleting the ISO9660 signature the USB will no longer be bootable.

Using the commands provided in [this post about undoing wipefs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/644558) and the [ISO9660 magic bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures#cite_ref-37) `[43 44 30 30 31]` I was able to restore the USB's bootable property with the following command:

```
echo -en '\x43\x44\x30\x30\x31' | sudo dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1 conv=notrunc seek=$((0x8001))
sudo partprobe /dev/sdb
```

This will effectively reverse the wipefs operation, returning the USB to its original state.